# I was accepted for membership "to" or "at" Sunnyside Country Club?

Tags: prepositions, collocation

Which is correct:

1. I was accepted for membership to Sunnyside Country Club.
2. I was accepted for membership at Sunnyside Country Club.

Comment: Thank you for your question. We are looking for thoughtful, intriguing questions posed as you would ask them of an expert, including evidence that you have put effort and research into the question. Please edit to share the results of your research. Questions which lack results of research may be closed. [(more)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

This would be dependent on whether the speaker was referring to the group/entity of the Club or to the location of Sunnyside Country Club.

For instance if you removed the words 'Sunnyside' and 'Country' and just left the word Club, a speaker would be more likely to choose the term "to".

I was accepted for membership to the club.

One might then wonder as to which 'club' you are referring, so it is necessary for the speaker to use the Proper Name.

Once the proper name is used however, it also has the interchangeable reference to the location of Sunnyside Country Club. If the speaker was referring to the location they would more commonly use 'at' in this sentence.

I was accepted for membership at Sunnyside Country Club. (as in over at their location, where they meet.)

Comment: This answer deserves an upvote if only for pointing out that *at* would indicate the place of induction, which wouldn't even have to be the place of membership: *I was inducted for membership into Skull & Bones at the Rotary Club as the Tomb was unavailable*. Prepositions licensed by membership include *in*, *of*, *on*, *to*, *at*, and *into* (per the link in my next comment). Please feel free to incorporate this discussion and link into your answer to make it the definitive statement on the usage.

Comment: Alas the link is too long for a comment. I've place it in an answer for your consideration. If you use it (or decide not to), I'll delete it later.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment to JA's answer.

Membership prepositions per the [Ngram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for%20membership%20*%2Cfor%20membership%20at%2Cfor%20membership%20into&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfor%20membership%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20was%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20are%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20were%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfor%20membership%20must%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20membership%20at%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfor%20membership%20into%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this is more of a US v UK English issue. I live in the UK and until about five years ago I had never heard the phrase 'membership to' - it was always 'membership of'. Suddenly, 'membership to' has become ubiquitous. As a Brit, 'membership to' makes no sense to me, but had I grown up in the USA it would doubtless seem normal.

Comment: Can you back up your claims with anything? Anything that supports the different between AmE and BrE

Comment: Nothing official, but UK dictionaries use 'of', not 'to' in their definitions of membership. Beyond that, it's anecdotal, based on 54 years of living in the UK and never hearing 'membership to' being said until the last five years; such transatlantic drift is common - a great many words and phrases have come to the UK from the US that were never heard here 20 years ago. As a professional editor, I also have a good understanding of English as it is spoken here. However, I cannot confirm definitely that it's a US v UK issue, which is why I suggested, rather than stated definitively, that it was.

Comment: That's sufficient support IMO. Can you add that type of explanation to the answer itself?

Comment: Hi Hank - I'm not sure if I've done that correctly - it's the first time I've posted on this site, so forgive me if I've done it incorrectly.

Comment: You did not. You added a new answer, instead. That being said, just delete this one and leave the other.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this is more of a US v UK English issue. UK dictionaries use 'of' when defining membership. Moreover, I've lived in the UK for over 50 years and until about five years ago I had never heard the phrase 'membership to' - it was always 'membership of'. Suddenly, 'membership to' has become ubiquitous. As a Brit, 'membership to' makes no sense to me, but had I grown up in the USA it would doubtless seem normal.

I'd add that I'm an editor by profession, so I have a reasonable grasp of UK English and am very alert to changes in usage.